# How to print array without square brackets?

Tags: java, arrays, string

When Arrays.toString is used, why is the output printed inside square brackets? What would I need to do if I don't want square brackets to be printed?

[image: Arrays.toString Output is inside square brackets!]

Comment: You can remove the first and last characters of a string pretty easily. With `substring()`for example. Or with `replace()`, if none of the values you actually want to print contain the characters you want to remove.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper Just make sure to handle the special case of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how `Arrays.toString` works. If you need a different behavior you would have to write a method yourself. In particular if you want all the elements to be separated by commas you can take advantage of the method `String.join` which does precisely that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you may remove the brackets from the resulting string produced by `Arrays.toString`.

However, you may simply join the array elements using any other delimiter with the help of `String::join` or a stream-based solution:

```java
Integer[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null};
String str = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .map(Objects::toString) // use null-safe conversion
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

// str = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null"
```

For array of primitive values like `int[]` an `IntStream` has to be used and its elements mapped to strings with `mapToObj`:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
String str = IntStream.of(arr)
        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("; ")); // use semicolon

// str = "1; 2; 3; 4; 5"
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the standard library provides a great class to join string with a specific delimiter, prefix and suffix.

```java
int[] nums = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(",", "", ""); //Delimiter, Prefix, Suffix
for (int num : nums) {
    stringJoiner.add(String.valueOf(num));
}
System.out.println(stringJoiner);
```

Or if you prefer streams:

```java
StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(",", "", "");
Arrays.stream(nums).mapToObj(String::valueOf).forEach(stringJoiner::add);
System.out.println(stringJoiner);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java String **replaceAll** method to remove the `brackets & commas`.
Here is an illustration:

```java
    int nums[] = {1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000};
    String s1 = Arrays.toString(nums);
    // Replacing all '[' , ',', ']'
    String s2 = Arrays.toString(nums).replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,", "");
        
    System.out.println( s1 );
    // [1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000]
    System.out.println( s2 );
    // 1 4 5 9 10 40 50 90 100 400 500 900 1000
```

The `replaceAll` method replaces each substring that matches oldSubstring with a substring that matches newSubstring in string.
For **multiple sub-strings replacements**:
we can use

```
input.replaceAll("string1|string2|string3","replacementString");
```

Comment: This is a rather brittle approach that works here because the input is integers, but what when the input itself contains brackets or commas?

Answer (score 0):

This is the toString method from java.util.Arrays

```
public static String toString(double[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";
    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        b.append(a[i]);
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.append(']').toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

so you can simply remove the braces yourself:

```
public static String myToString(double[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";
    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
        return "";

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        b.append(a[i]);
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It can use like this way to print array without any brackets.

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
public static void printArray(int[] xr){

    for(int i=0;i<xr.length;i++){
        System.out.print(xr[i]+", ");
    }
    System.out.print("\b\b");
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] ar={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
    printArray(ar);
}
```

}